# How to make a more elegant and shorter for loop with multiple internal functions and results

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

These are the steps I am following:

1. subset two matrices by a range of proportions (e.g. 80-85, 85-90)
2. run two separate distance measure functions for each subset of data
3. run a mantel using the distance matrix produced by each subset of data
4. produce a list of each test result, each with a unique name
5. produce a data frame of all the mantel-r results and their
   corresponding p-values

I have written code that will complete this process, but I feel there is a more elegant and better way to do so.  What I have works, but I would like to improve my R-skills, so any advice/ideas would be welcomed. I am not new to R, but I am far from being where I would like to be.

Also, my code produces unnecessary objects (i.e. SS, HB, sp.dis, epa.dis, and nam in the code below). They are not a big deal, but it would be nice to have code that doesn’t produce this side effect. A reproducible example (modeled after how my data is formatted) and the packages I’m using are below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(betapart)
library(vegan)

set.seed(2)
spe2<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:100,100,replace=T)))
spe2$Ag<-round(runif(100, min=0.4, max=1),2)
epa2<-data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:20,100,replace=T)))
epa2$Ag<-spe2$Ag

Mantel.List<-list()
List.names <- list()
for(i in seq(from=0.85, to=0.95,by=0.05 )){
  SS<-spe2 %>% 
    filter(Ag >= i & Ag < i+0.05)
  HB<-epa2 %>% 
    filter(Ag >= i & Ag < i+0.05)
  sp.dis<-beta.pair(decostand(SS[,1:ncol(SS)-1],'pa'))
  epa.dis<-vegdist(HB[,1:ncol(HB)-1],
                   method = 'euclidean')
  mnt<-mantel(sp.dis$beta.sor,epa.dis)
  Mantel.List[[length(Mantel.List)+1]] <- mnt
   nam<-paste('M.tt',i*100,sep='')
   List.names[[length(List.names)+1]] <- nam
   }
names(Mantel.List)<-List.names
Mantel.Results<-cbind(sapply(Mantel.List, function(x) x$statistic),sapply(Mantel.List, function(x) x$signif))
colnames(Mantel.Results)<-c('Mantel-r', 'p-value')
Mantel.Results
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Linus is there a way to migrate this post to codereview.stackexchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done two things two try to make this code a little better. First, I eliminated all the unnecessary objects, and I've done this by using data.table package, which is usually the most efficient way to handle data.frames, cause it doesn't make copies of itself when subsetting.

Secondly, instead of using a for loop, I'm using an apply function. Note the assigner `<<-` inside `doit()`, which will replace the object outside the function.

Here's my suggestion:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(2)
spe2<-as.data.table(data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:100,100,replace=T))))
spe2$Ag<-round(runif(100, min=0.4, max=1),2)
epa2<-as.data.table(data.frame(replicate(3,sample(1:20,100,replace=T))))
epa2$Ag<-spe2$Ag

    doitAll=function(dt1,dt2){
  Mantel.List<-list()
  List.names <- list()

  doit=function(x,dt1,dt2){
    mnt<-mantel(beta.pair(decostand(dt1[Ag >= x & Ag < x+0.05,1:(ncol(dt1)-1),with=F],'pa'))$beta.sor,
                vegdist(dt2[Ag >= x & Ag < x+0.05,1:(ncol(dt2)-1),with=F],
                        method = 'euclidean'))
    Mantel.List[[length(Mantel.List)+1]] <<- mnt
    nam<-paste('M.tt',x*100,sep='')
    List.names[[length(List.names)+1]] <<- nam
  }
  sapply(seq(from=0.85, to=0.95,by=0.05 ),doit,dt1=dt1,dt2=dt2)

  names(Mantel.List)<-List.names
  Mantel.Results<-cbind(sapply(Mantel.List, function(x) x$statistic),sapply(Mantel.List, function(x) x$signif))
  colnames(Mantel.Results)<-c('Mantel-r', 'p-value')
  return(Mantel.Results)
}

doitAll(dt1=spe2,dt2=epa2)
```

It might be a little hard to read, but it's surely more efficient.

Comment: Ricardo, when I run this, I get an Erro: Error in FUN(x[[i]],...): unused argument (dt1 = list (x1 = C(18,... Then lists all of spe2.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten that the data frames had to be converted, and the function arguments were different. Should work just fine now.

Comment: Ricardo, that works, thank you! One more question for improvement. Do you have a suggestion of how to put the Mantel.List<-list() &
List.names <- list() into the function? I've been playing around with it but failing miserably. If I forget to run that little bid of code before running the function, I get multiple copies of the results combined into one list.

Comment: Can't you just make a larger function that incorporates the remaining code and the previous function?

Comment: If I simply paste the code into the function, I get an error: Error in Mantel.List[[length(Mantel.List) + 1]] <<- mnt : 
  object 'Mantel.List' not found

Comment: I've edited the answer to incorporate everything inside. I didn't test it, so if there's any problem, let me know.

Comment: Yep, that's it. Not sure what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Just realized your script returns different results than my original for loop. Not sure how I missed this. I ran each group separately (i.e. 85 -<90, 90 - <95) to double check, and the original for loop is returning the correct results. I don't know enough about the data.table package to know what's going wrong

Comment: Sorry about that. I should've checked. The problem was where I selected the columns from data.tables. It's fixed now.